# What kind of Javascript rich text editor support formula?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, latex, mathjax, katex

Is there a Javascript rich text editor that allows me to choose the formula through the toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

[Tiny MCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/) has plugins that can be installed and add equation functionality in the Tiny MCE editor toolbar.

See this plugin for Latex:
https://www.codecogs.com/latex/integration/tinymce_v4/install.php